# Pyinstaller : module could not be found error (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller, eel

I was getting a 'Failed to load script error', when I checked it with -F the cmd line says

```
File "site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 3, in module 
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found.
```

As it is saying it is pandas error, I tried reninstalling pandas by `pip install pandas` but it didn't work.

What is the fix for this? Also is there any alternative for Pyinstaller that supports `eel`?? in pyinstaller I usually give `pyintaller -m eel app.py Web --noconsole --onefile` for supporting the eel UI

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it is not pretty and doesn't work with --onefile:

```
python -m eel app.py Web
pip install -r requirements.txt --target=dist/app --ignore-installed
```

In the requirements all the python packages are what you need.
You might need to add some extra package the requirements like setuptools or astor